# MariaDB Virtual Columns - Can I calculate age?

Tags: mariadb

I'm studying MariaDB now. My task is to create a database for ageing patients research in our clinic.

I have dates of birth (`birthdate`) and date of death (`deathdate`) for died patients.

I need to have fields:

- `is_alive` - BOOLEAN - calculated from `deathdate` and today's date
- `age` - INT - calculated from `birthdate`, `deathdate` and today's date - if `deathdate` is not null, so patient is not alive and `age=deathdate-birthdate` . If `deathdate` is null, then `age=todaydate-birthdate`

Is it possible to calculate such a fields by Virtual columns or I should to make a VIEW ?

Comment: Step 1:  Write a `SELECT` that correctly computes `age` and `is_alive`.  You can't do simple subtraction; see the datetime functions available.  Step 2:  `ALTER` the table to add those expressions to define virtual functions.

Comment: And you can create an event to do the updates: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-event/

Comment: Thank you, @Hackerman . I will try this method and if it will work, I'll post the answer here.